# Verify integrity of Apache file

Tags: thrift, public-key

This journey is embarrassingly long which makes me feel like I'm missing something obvious. My question: Is there a more direct approach at verifying an Apache release? or rather, where did I go wrong?

I am trying to verify my download of Apache Thrift by following their instructions listed [here](http://www.apache.org/info/verification.html).

```
Mateos-MBP:Thrift.nosync mateo$ 
    gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key DE885DD3
gpg: key 89AC4BA7DE885DD3: 73 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 89AC4BA7DE885DD3: "Sander Striker <striker@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key 6635B6C0DE885DD3: 10 duplicate signatures removed
gpg: key 6635B6C0DE885DD3: 295 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 6635B6C0DE885DD3: "Sander Striker <striker@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:              unchanged: 2
Mateos-MBP:Thrift.nosync mateo$ gpg --verify thrift-0.11.0.tar.gz.asc thrift-0.11.0.tar.gz
gpg: Signature made Sun Dec  3 12:24:40 2017 MST
gpg:                using RSA key 8CD87F186F06E958EFCA963D76BD340FC4B75865
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
Mateos-MBP:Thrift.nosync mateo$
```

Ok, so apparently Thrift needs a public key with the ID of 8CD87F186....
not striker. (or that's what the hackers WANT me to think) So I look on pgp.mit.edu (not found) and again on keyserver.php.com (not found). Then I search in Google which takes me over to [Apache Public Key files](https://people.apache.org/keys/committer/). Feeling better that I'm back on a legitimate site. I find my key signed by 'jensg', copy/paste into my own text file, then verify the file albeit with a non trusted signature. Yay, mission accomplished.

```
Mateos-MBP:Thrift.nosync mateo$ gpg --verify thrift-0.11.0.tar.gz.asc thrift-0.11.0.tar.gz
gpg: Signature made Sun Dec  3 12:24:40 2017 MST
gpg:                using RSA key 8CD87F186F06E958EFCA963D76BD340FC4B75865
gpg: Good signature from "Jens Geyer <jensgeyer@hotmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Jens Geyer <jensg@apache.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 8CD8 7F18 6F06 E958 EFCA  963D 76BD 340F C4B7 5865
```

So, is there a more direct approach at verifying an Apache release?

Comment: You already found https://www.apache.org/info/verification.html

Comment: Yes, however the instructions do not seem to be correct since DE885DD3 wasn't the public key I needed to use. Luckily Google pointed me to a different page https://people.apache.org/keys/committer/. So am I bad at following instructions or are the instructions wrong?

Comment: [The ASF hosts (IIRC) around 250 projects today](http://www.apache.org/index.html#projects-list). These instructions are meant to be **generic** for all of them. As you might already guessed, not all people are working on all projects. The id `DE885DD3` you mentioned stems form the **output** of the command issue above (same page) `gpg --verify httpd-2.0.44.tar.gz.asc httpd-2.0.44.tar.gz`. Different package, different output ...

Comment: The [download page](http://thrift.apache.org/download) also clearly points to the KEYS file: "*The [KEYS](https://www.apache.org/dist/thrift/KEYS) file contains the public key(s) used for signing releases.*"

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Focusing on the verification instructions and not using the next link (public keys) referenced on the download page was where I went wrong.